# PG Admin 4 (WEB) and inititail logon as user postgress without password

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a fresh install of a database on AWS. I have installed PG Admin 4 for Web and set up for a user login. This works.

I find it is not possible to connect to the localhost database using 'postgres' as a user, without a password. This appears to be enforced by the dialog. Is there a way around this enforcement?  How would a user only having web access ALTER this ROLE? I would expect this to be relaxed for the initial login.

The database is local to the webserver and the web server is remote for the user.

Comment: Is pgAdmin asking for the database user's password, or for the pgAdmin "master password" or the pgAdmin user account password?

Comment: The database user's password. There does not seem to be a master password in use for the web since there is a web logon. It seems very few people use the web version,

Comment: I don't see how this is not a duplicate.  The pg_hba.conf works the way it works.  Maybe you would prefer that it work differently, but that doesn't make the question not a duplicate.

Comment: The script should allow for assigning a password if the identity of the postgres user cannot be assumed by the server for the initial login.  It;s a gap.

Comment: @jjanes The config files might not come into it, they work out of the box for local connections? Although if they were relevant it would be preferable to changing sudoers to allow Apache to become the postgres system user.

Answer (score 0):

TL:DR This logon is not a peer logon as the postgres *nix user.

It's a gap in the install. A manual step will always be required to add a password for postgres for anyone wanting to use the interface for initial USER/ROLE creation. It would be nice to have had this opportunity in the setup script.

I suppose it is expected that most administrators would also add other users/roles at this time and these would be supplied to the users. Changes to config files would still be managed. They are not getting shell access.